# AWS Amplify with Ping or Okta

Tags: amazon-web-services, ping, aws-amplify, okta

Does AWS Amplify work without Cognito as Idp or Identity broker . We have use case to use Amplify react libraries to Authenticate Ping or Okta and Authorize STS

Answer (score 1):

From the image below you can see there are other Login mechanisms you can use like Google, Apple, and Facebook. Unfortunately Okta is not supported through the Amplify console directly, so you still have to use Cognito to handle the request and then use an "Authorizer" Lambda function from Cognito to Okta as per this article:
[AWS Amplify, Cognito, and OpenID connect identity provider](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-application-with-aws-amplify-amazon-cognito-and-an-openid-connect-identity-provider/)

Another option might be to tie the Okta authentication into each web app directly using the Okta SDKs here:
[Okta Languages & SDKs](https://developer.okta.com/code/)

[image: Current Amplify Login mechanisms (May 2021)]